# Stop mouse from switching to active window

Tags: windows-10

Problem is, that whenever a new window comes up, the mouse pointer is moved automatically to the center of that window.

This is highly annoying, I want the mouse to stay where it was.

Do you know of any registry settings or Windows options to turn this off?

X-Mouse is turned on intentionally and should stay turned on.

Operating system is Windows Server 2019, latest update.

Comment: By X-Mouse, do you mean [this windows setting](https://winaero.com/enable-xmouse-window-tracking-windows-10/)? To narrow it down, can you disable X-Mouse and see if the behaviour disappears? I know you want to keep X-Mouse on, but it would then indicate it's inherent to X-Mouse or some other setting. Do you have any other input altering software installed, such AutoHotKey?

Comment: Did you do a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mouse+snaps+to+center+of+new+window) for this? The [first link](https://www.lotro.com/forums/showthread.php?355987-Mouse-cursor-snapping-to-center-of-screen) just might have a clue or two...

Comment: I did multiple searches without finding a solution.

Comment: Doesn't happen with standard Windows 10. You have set some other setting or have not really disabled Xmouse Window Tracking.

Comment: @harrymc: This might be so. I want X-mouse without automatic mouse movement. How to set that?